# How do I define the distributive property for my operator?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, algebra

I would like `Simplify` and `Expand` to work so that

```
a^(b+c) <-> a^b + a^c
```

I am beginner so it's not clear to me what the best way to achieve this is. I have  a basic understanding of patterns, so I was thinking something like

```
Wedge /: Simplify[Wedge[a_,b_]+Wedge[a_,c_]] := Wedge[a,b+c]
```

But this doesn't work, raising an error regarding `Wedge` being too deep for a rule to be found.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you don't need Simplify, just `Wedge /: Wedge[a_, b_] + Wedge[a_, c_] := Wedge[a, b + c]` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting:

```
$Assumptions = {Wedge[a_, b_] + Wedge[a_, c_] == Wedge[a_, b_ + c_]}
```

This should work (at least for simple cases) for `Simplify`.

Alternatively, define

```
WedgeExpand[expr_] :=  expr //. {Wedge[a_, b_ + c_] :> Wedge[a, b] + Wedge[a, c]}
WedgeGather[expr_] :=  expr //. {Wedge[a_, b_] + Wedge[a_, c_] :> Wedge[a, b + c]}
```

and use the `TransformationFunctions` option of `Simplify`. E.g.

```
Simplify[Wedge[X, Y] + Wedge[X, Z] == Wedge[X, Y + Z],
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, WedgeExpand, WedgeGather}]
```

will return `True`.

Comment: It seems there is no way of getting around the `tagpos` depth issue (which seems to be the fundamental issue here), so I think I will just need to use `TransformationFunctions`.  I ended up just defining a new `WedgeSimplify` function that calls `Simplify` with the appropriate rules.  Thank you for your help.